# unable to switch root

Tags: root

I got the following message when I supply p/w to switch root with command

```
$ sudo -l

env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User riwajt may run the following commands on riwaj:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -l` is the command to *list* allowed and forbidden commands. From `man sudo`:

```
 -l, --list  If no command is specified, list the allowed (and forbidden)
             commands for the invoking user (or the user specified by the
             -U option) on the current host.
```

You my be confusing `-l` with `-i` or `--login`:

```
 -i, --login
             Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
             base entry as a login shell.
```

or with `su -l`:

```
   -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
       the user logged in directly.
```